# Except isnt working in my python 3.6 program. Why?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.6

So, I have a python program with a class and logger. Here is the code:

```
import logging

path2log = "logs/1.pylog"

LOG_FORMAT = "%(levelname)s - %(name)s (%(asctime)s) : %(message)s"

#existing log levels are:
#Debug
#Info
#Warning
#Error
#Critical

logging.basicConfig(filename = path2log,
                    level = logging.DEBUG,
                    format = LOG_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger("1.py.logger 'CONSOLE'")

class Emperor():

    try:
        def __init__(self, name, famname, level):

            try:
                self.name = name
                self.famname = famname
                self.level = level

                try:
                    logger.info("Emperor created with name:")
                    logger.info(self.name)
                    logger.info("family name:")
                    logger.info(self.famname)
                    logger.info("and level:")
                    logger.info(self.level)
                except TypeError:
                    logger.error("Missing perameter creating object in emperor class")
            except TypeError:
                logger.error("Missing perameter creating object in emperor class.")

    except TypeError:
        logger.error("Missing perameter creating object in emperor class.")
```

But all of the excepts in the def **init** area don't do anything. I still get the error when running the program. How do I fix this?

Edit: [Here is the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHvue.png)

Comment: Why are you nesting try/excepts?

Comment: show the errors

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your posted code doesn't do anything,  for lack of a main program.  You never user `Emperor`.  What result do you expect when you put a function `def` as the sole command of a `try-except` block?

Comment: it's very likely that the exception you're getting doesn't come from any of the code you've shown. Instead, it's probably being generated somewhere that you're trying to create an `Emperor` instance, but you're passing the wrong number of arguments, so it doesn't work. That's an error *at the place of the call*, not an inside the `Emperor` class. You need to put the `try`/`except` statements around that call site, rather than in `Emperor`.

Comment: When you are creating the object/instance of the class you are passing only 2 variables but the `__init__()` requires 3 variables. This is the error you are getting. You never reach the definition/body of `__init__()` so none of the exception is caught.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having trying to catch your exception has to do with a misunderstanding of where the exception is being generated. When you call an function with the wrong arguments, you get an error *from the call*, not from within the function.

No `try`/`except` code in or around the function definition will be able to catch that exception, since the function's code doesn't ever start running (and the definition happened without error earlier, so a `try`/`except` around the `def` statement won't help). Only the code around the call can do something if the call itself fails.